Why is the databricks workflow trigger status always paused?
I create a workflow job via Asset Bundle. However, after deploying the job to the databricks the trigger status is always paused even no matter how I update the cron expression. I can manually trigger it successfully.


I cannot figure out why. Am I missing something? All the tasks in the workflow job is DLT pipeline, and the later one depends on the previous one

is the cron_status key set to "PAUSED"? If so, set this to "UNPAUSED"
